# How to count the rows which contains non zero values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT round(COUNT(dmd_1wk),2) AS NBR_ITEMS_1WK
  FROM table;
```

Field dmd_1wk has so many zeros in it. How do I Count the non zero values?

Comment: COUNT() returns an integer.  So what is the point of ROUND() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methinks [bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet)s answer is probably what you are really looking for, as it sounds like you just want to count non-zeros; but this will get you a count of zero and non-zero items if that's not the case:

```
SELECT 
  ROUND(SUM(CASE NVL(dmd_1wk, 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 2) AS "Zeros",
  ROUND(SUM(CASE NVL(dmd_1wk, 0) != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 2) AS "NonZeros"
FROM table
```

Although there is no point in rounding a whole number, I've included your original ROUNDs as I'm guessing you're using it for formatting, but you might want to use:

```
TO_CHAR(SUM(...), '999.00')
```

as that's the intended function for formatting numbers.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you just need to add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
      round(COUNT(dmd_1wk),2) AS NBR_ITEMS_1WK
FROM table
WHERE dmd_1wk <> 0;
```

If you want the count of both non-zero and zero values, then you can use something like:

```
SELECT 
   round(COUNT(case when dmd_1wk <> 0 then dmd_1wk end),2) AS NBR_ITEMS_1WK_NonZero,
   round(COUNT(case when dmd_1wk = 0 then dmd_1wk end),2) AS NBR_ITEMS_1WK_Zero
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**: Case Statement. This may be useful if you need to continue to process all rows (which a where clause would prevent).

```
 SELECT count(case when dmd_1wk = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as NonZeroCount FROM MyTable
```

**Method 2**: Where Clause.

```
 SELECT
   count(1) as NonZeroCount
 FROM
   MyTable
 WHERE
  dmd_1wk <> 0
```

Comment: That is correct. The where clause will process fewer rows. The case statement method will process all rows. Both options may be useful depending on your other application needs

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer another solution using `NULLIF` since `COUNT` won't count NULL values:

```
SELECT round(COUNT(NULLIF(dmd_1wk,0)),2) AS NBR_ITEMS_1WK
FROM table;
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/580f6/3).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter them.

```
SELECT round(COUNT(dmd_1wk),2) AS NBR_ITEMS_1WK
FROM table
WHERE dmd_1wk <> 0;
```